# Move screen transition of ViewController class from another class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I have exactly the same problem as the title.

Please see the code below.
Each code is listed in a separate file.

I wrote a method for screen transition in the ViewController class (as func goToSecondView ()).
Then we decided to create an instance within the "iconATapped" method in another file (FirstFile) and make the screen transition of ViewController.

However, it did not succeed and issued the following error.

```
let next = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondView")
//Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This error works when the Action method is invoked.

Please tell me the way to solve this.

```
//FirstFile

import UIKit

class goNextPage: UIView {

    @IBAction func iconATapped(_ sender: Any) {
        ViewController.goToSecondView()
    }

}


//SecondFile

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func goToSecondView(){
        let next = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondView")
        self.present(next,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: Why did you put `goToSecondView` in another view controller? What's wrong with putting it in the first file?

Comment: Either your `storyboard` variable is nil OR you don't have identifier named `secondView` in your storyboard.

Comment: Add your code for intialisation of storyboard variable too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ViewController.goToSecondView() and in the goToSecondView you are using self

```
self.present(next,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

here your self will be nil as you are not using the variable of ViewController but its class name. So there is no instance of ViewController and hence resulting in nil.

try creating the variable of ViewController in your first file and then try presenting new Vc. Hope this helps!